# WP7 - How can I display a menu when holding down my finger on a ListBoxItem

Tags: windows-phone-7

Almost everywhere in Windows Phone (for instance in the People hub), when you hold down your finger anywhere, a context-menu-ish menu pops up that says "Refresh".

How can I recreate this menu in my own application? I don't even know what to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)'s (August 2011) ContextMenu.

```
       xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

       <ListBoxItem>
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
               <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                     <toolkit:MenuItem Header="something" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
                     <toolkit:MenuItem Header="something else" Command="{Binding SomeOtherCommand}" />
               </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Can you link to where I can find the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll file? I can't seem to find the proper reference, and I do have that toolkit installed.

Comment: mine is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Aug11\Bin

Comment: You can download the toolkit for Silverlight and for Silverlight for Windows Phone from here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com

Comment: That installer doesn't work for me, I installed it through NuGet. So where is it located then? I don't see it in the given path.